# Comparing contents of files

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have two tab delimited files of 15 columns each and n and m number of rows.

The number of rows in file 1  are greater than that of file2, say file 1 has 15 rows
that are not present in file2

how can I find out these rows?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `diff`?

Comment: diff may not help to find out the 15 rows...or?

Comment: @Kent Of course it does. Depending on the options, it will prefix the lines with `<`, `>` or `+`, `-`.

Answer (score 2):

The `comm` command will find lines that are unique to either file, or common to both.

```
comm -23 <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 )
```

will print the lines only in file1 (lines only in file2 and common lines are suppressed by the `-2` and `-3` options. The files must be sorted; it doesn't really matter how they are sorted, as long as they are both sorted on the same key and in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

does this help?

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

The [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) command may help, particularly the **-a** option:

> -a FILENUM
>       print unpairable lines coming from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2